# Changing how files are sorted in Finder

Tags: applescript

I have the following simple script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set sort column of list view options of Finder window 1 to size column
end tell
```

I get no errors but nothing happens, the files in the window remain sorted by modification date. The result says: `size column`.

Comment: I discovered if I manually click on a different folder and then go back to the original folder, the files are then sorted by size. So how do I refresh the view with applescript?

Comment: Only work around I could find was changing the target away from the current folder and back to it which is less than ideal.